# How to represent a discontinuity in discretized data

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, interpolation

Let us say that there is some function f that we want to approximate.

Let us say we are given a vector v that has samples of that funciton at known values, such as:

[0.5, 0.7, -1.3 ...]

Let us assume that we actually know what f is, but we want to approximate for whatever reason (maybe f is too expensive to compute).

If you know f is continuous a decent approximation of the function using the samples is to  connect every 2 samples by a straight line, i.e. each piece is a piecewise linear interpolation of the 2 endpoints.

Something like this:

[image]

However, let us say that the original function is piece-wise continuous, for example a step function. We know that for example there is a discontinuity occurring between index i and index i+1.

How would we represent such a discontinuity in the data? i.e. what is the most robust way to "interpolate" between the value i and the value i+1 to reproduce the discontinuity?

Comment: Since we have no information about the discontinuity. might be a step or a vertical asymptote or whatever, there is no good way to approximate this. We need more information about f to do so. If we know it is a step, maybe linear interpolation is not a bad way to handle it (or simply do not interpolate f in  the intervall between index i and index i+1 at all).

Comment: What you describe is an unusual situation.  Normally, if you *know* that there is a discontinuity, then you know where it is on both axes, and if you need to reproduce it then it should be represented in your time series data.

Comment: Show an example of what you call a discontinuity, otherwise we can't answer.

Comment: digital signal IS always discontinuous.. analog isn't. | digital signal will at most max out the binary, will not be continuous.

Comment: "we actually know what f is" -- then you'd typically approximate `f` on each continuous segment using whatever method you want, and handle the segments independently. Let's say you want to approximate `tan(x)` -- you'll approximate it only in the [-π, π] interval, and for all other `x`s reduce it to that interval.